# GWT serversided threads

Tags: multithreading, gwt

I'm using the GWT RPC calls to talk to another server. I do this asynchronous by using threads. So the RPC service is returning before all threads are finished.

My problem now is that the HttpURLConnection I use, works fine when I use it woutjout thread, but crashes when I use it in a seperate thread. The reason for that I is (I think) beache the RPC call is returning before al threads are finished.

Did anybody had the same problem and found a solution for it?

best regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your assumption that the crash is being caused by the RPC call returning too soon, you could use `Thread.join()` on each of the threads you created to work asynchronously. This will block the main thread until all your background work is done.

Comment: ok, this question is so long ago, that I forgott what the problem really was.... but I guess that answer is fine and I can close this question :P